# How to change HTTP response code in mitmproxy?

Tags: mitmproxy

Using [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/), it’s possible to change the body of a response, and even from the command line:

```bash
$ mitmproxy --listen-port 8888 --ssl-insecure \
    --modify-body '#~m POST & ~u /session & ~s#\{.*\}#@/tmp/sessionReplacement`
```

However, this replaces only the *body* of the response. I need to change the response code as well, from 200 to 403 for my tests. Apart from the body, I could also replace headers, but the response code in HTTP is not in a header.

With the user interface, it’s possible: I can define another interception, then edit the response in many many ways, but that is laborious and (too) slow.

Comment: One possibility would be write a little plugin where you can first test the response if it matches your pattern and then change the response code and other parameters. There are a lot of sample plugins on the mitmproxy web site.

Answer (score 1):

I takes a bit of learning, but since the configuration of interceptors and the `modify_body` options is also non-trivial, in the end writing my own Plugin was indeed the simplest solution. Take this as a template:

```py
"""
Manipulate a response, based on a fixed matcher.

Run as follows: mitmproxy -s response-manipulator.py
"""
import logging
import re


class ResponseManipulator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session_url = re.compile(".*/whatever")

    def response(self, flow):
        if flow.request.method == "POST" and \
                self.session_url.fullmatch(flow.request.pretty_url) and \
                flow.response.status_code == 200:
            flow.response.status_code = 403
            flow.response.reason = b"Forbidden"
            flow.response.content = b"{\"test\":true}"


addons = [ResponseManipulator()]
```